# Magento - Magebig extension Ajax infinite scroll not working properly first set of products is repeating

Tags: ajax, magento2

Magebig Ajax infinite scroll extension is not working in the latest package of magento. The package is working fine in the 2.3 magento version . Now we have updated to magento 2.4.2 ., the ajax infinite scroll in product page sometimes shows duplicate products to be clear ...It repeats the first set of products while clicking the "Load more" button it doesn't consider it as a second page while clicking the button pagination is not also adding in the URL sometimes .

**Magento version - 2.4.2
Magebig extension - Ajax infinite scroll https://doc.magebig.com/martfury/extensions/**

Answer (score 0):

Atlast found an solution ..., there is a upgrade version of my theme extension there the issue is fixed. Thankyou.